# How to monitor GlassFish thread pool via asadmin interface

Tags: glassfish, monitoring

I'm trying to use the asadmin interface to monitor a thread-pool on GlassFish 3.1.1.  I'm executing the following command:

```
asadmin get -m server.network.my-listener.thread-pool.*
```

and I'm getting data back, but most of it has lastsampletime = -1 (so the related data is zero; and is worthless).

Note: I've also tried the REST interface, which I believe asadmin delegates to, and the JMX interface.  Same problem: much of the data has lastsampletime = -1.

I've already turned monitoring to HIGH for all modules.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like redeploying my application was necessary for the monitoring to actually get values.  Perhaps I interpreted the manual incorrectly but it seems to suggest that a restart/redeploy wouldn't be required:

[Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1 Administration Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ablvp.html#ablvr)

Also, it is weird that the following shows there is no monitoring data:

```
asadmin get -m server.thread-pools.thread-pool.http-thread-pool.*
```

Instead you must go through a specific network listener like:

```
asadmin get -m server.network.http-listener-2.thread-pool.*
```

It also took me by surprise that enabling thread-pool monitoring IS NOT enough to see thread pool statistics.  You must also enable http-service monitoring:

```
asadmin enable-monitoring
asadmin set server.monitoring-service.module-monitoring-levels.thread-pool=HIGH
asadmin set server.monitoring-service.module-monitoring-levels.http-service=HIGH
```

Comment: I didn't understand the issue again and found the answer the second time. Sorry I cannot vote up again, but many thanks for question and answer @Ryan!

Answer (score 5):

That's all you should need to do.

1. Enable monitoring, set to `HIGH`, for the http-service module on the DAS, stand-alone instance, or cluster you want to monitor.
2. Deploy an app to the DAS, stand-alone instance, or cluster and make http-requests.
3. `asadmin get -m *instancename*.network.*listener*.thread-pool.*`

Looks like you are monitoring DAS, since you are using `asadmin get -m server.network.my-listener.thread-pool.*.`

I deployed a simple war to DAS and made a bunch of http requests.  I see the corethreads-count and maxthreads-count have last sample time as -1.  And the remaining statistics have actual last sample times.

```
asadmin get -m "server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.*"
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-count = 0
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-description = Core number of threads in the thread pool
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-lastsampletime = -1
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-name = CoreThreads
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-starttime = 1320764890444
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.corethreads-unit = count
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-count = 5
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-description = Provides the number of request processing threads currently in the listener thread pool
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-lastsampletime =  1320765351708
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-name = CurrentThreadCount
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-starttime = 1320764890445
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-unit = count
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-count = 0
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-description = Provides the number of request processing threads currently in use in the listener thread pool serving requests
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-lastsampletime = 1320765772814
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-name = CurrentThreadsBusy 
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-starttime = 1320764890445
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-unit = count
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.dotted-name = server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-count = 0
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-description = Maximum number of threads allowed in the thread pool
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-lastsampletime = -1
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-name = MaxThreads
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-starttime = 1320764890443
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.maxthreads-unit = count
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-count = 31
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-description = Provides the total number of tasks, which were executed by the thread pool
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-lastsampletime = 1320765772814
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-name = TotalExecutedTasksCount
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-starttime = 1320764890444
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.totalexecutedtasks-unit = count

Command get executed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

To instantly enable monitoring without restart use enable-monitoring command

```
enable-monitoring
enable-monitoring --modules jvm=LOW
enable-monitoring --modules thread-pool=HIGH
enable-monitoring --modules http-service=HIGH
enable-monitoring --modules jdbc-connection-pool=HIGH
```

The trick is that thread-pool and http-service modules must have high level to get monitoring info.

For more info refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/monitoring.htm#GSADG00558